# How can I add Normal Java project capabilities to EJB project in Eclipse (.ear)?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ejb, ear

Just started working with EJB (already developed project).

Imported the project from git and converted it to Maven project. However the project looks like a normal folder structure unlike regular java project. I cannot have any eclipse Java capabilities in side those files. Though they are Java files they look like class files to me with different symbol (can see that in image).

It won't compile unless I do maven build. Eclipse not showing any errors for those files even there are compile errors.

Running each time maven kills time and its irritating too.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.  How to make that a normal Java project with eclipse compiler capabilities.

What configuration I have to do achieve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the command `mvn eclipse:eclipse` from the root folder of the project. It will create eclipse configuration files after which the project can be imported in Eclipse.

Comment: It is already been imported and running fine. But unlike a normal java project the folder structure is showing, not packages.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Did you try running the command? I do not see any .classpath etc eclipse files in the screenshot. Also, not sure which view you are using, try the Package Explorer or Project Explorer view. If you're using Navigator view it appears as normal files.

Comment: Thanks for helping Vasan. When executed the command and tried to import the project, it imported as 3 projects which I don't want. And I am looking in project explorer only, not navigator.

Comment: It will generate as many eclipse projects as there are Maven projects. How many maven projects do you have? What structure in eclipse are you expecting?

Comment: You are correct there are 3 pom's. Is it possible to get a single project with differnt packages, instead of folders ?

Comment: Run the maven command I provided on the parent project folder (which also has a POM). Then import the parent as a project. Now, if you're using Eclipse Mars version > 4.5M5, you can switch to hierarchical view from Project Explorer (Downward menu triangle on right side -> Project Presentation -> Hierarchical). See this (scroll to Nested/Hierarchical view of projects): https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.5/M5/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122196/discussion-between-ss--and-vasan).