# Synchronizing new Eclipse project with GitHub repository

Tags: eclipse, git, github, ejb

I have an EJB project in Eclipse that synchronizes with a repository in GitHub, this works fine, I have in `.gitignore` all the configuration files.

Now I have another laptop to set up, so I created a new EJB project in Eclipse (this creates some configuration files) and attempted to pull the new files from GitHub. In the end, I need to have all the repository files + configuration files in the laptop.

I initialized the Eclipse project positioned in the local directory and tried the `git pull` command:

```
git init 
git remote add origin https://github.com/xxxx/my-repo
git pull https://github.com/xxxx/my-repo
```

But I get:

```
From https://github.com/xxxx/my-repo
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I just need to pull the GitHub repository files into my Eclipse project. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You shouldn't use git init. You should use git clone, to clone the already existing repo.

Comment: But git clone requires that the destination folder is empty, isn’t it?

Comment: Yes, so? Clone the repo to an empty folder, and then add whatever you want to that folder (notmally, nothing except the files that eclipse will create all by itself when importing the project).

Answer (score 0):

As commented:

- clone the repo first (in an empty folder indeed)
- then, if you need to, as seen in "[How can I add Normal Java project capabilities to EJB project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39224157/6309) ", run a `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to create eclipse configuration files.
- finally, [import it to Eclipse](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-importproject.htm) (File Import/  General > Existing Project into Workspace).

Comment: I think that would enable Java capabilities to the project, and what I need is to enable Java + EJB project capabilities

Comment: @ps0604 it would *adds* java capabilities, while retaining EJB ones.

Comment: But when I clone the project from GitHub I don't have any EJB-specific Eclipse configuration, how would I retain EJB capabilities?

Comment: @ps0604 I assumed you already had those properties. But if not, once you have imported your maven project with Java properties, you can add EJB ones: https://ibytecode.com/blog/how-to-create-a-ejb-3-x-project-using-maven-in-eclipse-part-1/

Comment: In that link it says how to create new EJBs, not how to convert a Java project to EJB project

Comment: @ps0604 then create an EJB project, then edit the properties of said project, and select "Java": that should add the Java nature on top of the existing EJB nature.